# Excel VBA shell script that executes python script not working

Tags: python, vba, excel, shell

I have a VBA script as given below that executes a python script that writes values to Excel workbooks.

```
Dim args
Dim Ret_Val
args = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\helloWorld.py"
Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Python27\python.exe " & args, vbNormalFocus)
```

The helloWorld.py is given below:

```
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
rb = xlrd.open_workbook("/a/b/StubProto.xlsm")
wb = copy(rb)
ws1 = wb.get_sheet(0)
ws1.write(1, 11, "Hello World")
wb.save("StubProto.xlsm")
```

The above code works OK on its own in a Windows environment but does not work on a VBA environment. It does not seem to return anything in a VBA environment.

Is there some thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have a VBA script that does the same thing, this is how it looks:

```
args = """" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\helloWorld.py"" P"
output = ShellRun("""C:\Python27\python.exe"" " & args)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a directory in the args path that had a space in between. Removing the space in the path of the python script fixed the error.